# Uploading my iTunes music that I saved on a flash drive to iTunes on my new computer then downloading it to my iPod Touch

Tags: windows-7, windows, ipod, touch

I had an old computer with Windows XP. I transferred all my music, at least I hoped I had to a flash drive. Also, my computer kept giving me error messages that it could no longer sync to my iPod Touch First Generation.

I reformatted my iPod back to original factory specs on the old computer. I have a new computer with Windows 7. I can't transfer my music from my flash drive to the iTunes Library. I also can't transfer it to my iPod.

I keep getting the message "Songs cannot be added to the iPod because all of its space has been reserved for data." There's nothing in the iPod memory. It's clear.

What can I do? I want my music back.

Comment: when you attach your USB to the new computer and open it, what do you see on the drive?

Comment: You mean the flash drive?

Comment: yes...the flash drive.

Comment: I see all the material I put on it from my old computer. Documents, photos and the icon for ITunes, but all the music I had on my Ipod and old computer is gone. All the stuff I had b ought from ITunes is gone.

Comment: I have another Ipod Nano which has a lot of the music I had on it. But it was originally Macintosh formatted and won't run on this machine. The Machine I formatted it on originally is unfortunately long gone. Is there anything I can do or am i just going to have to start all over again buying my music from ITunes for my Ipod Touch?

Answer (score 0):

> **I can't transfer my music from my flash drive to the ITunes Library.**
>
> **What can I do? I want my music back.**

The Music part:

Your music (both purchased and ripped from CDs) should be on the old XP computer. You will have to go back to that computer to retreive it.

To locate where they have been saved to:

- Open iTunes on the xp computer
- goto ***Edit*** and select ***Prefrerences***[image: Edit and prefs]
- Go to the Advanced tab
  [image: itunes2]
  In my case it is ***C:\Users\carl\Music\iTunes\iTunes Media***

So you would want to follow that path in your computer for your file location. Once you get to the iTunes media folder;

- Right click
- Copy the folder
- Paste to your pen/thumb drive.

You should now have a copy of all your music.

The transfer part to your new computer:

I would import the folder so iTunes will do it's sorting magic. Copy the file from your thumb/pen drive to a place on your new computers hard drive. like **Music**.

Open iTunes,

- Select ***File***
- Then select ***Add folder to library***[image: itunes3]
- Go to the file you saved from your thumb/pen drive and click ***Select Folder*** at the bottom right.

iTunes should be importing your music to your new itunes on your new computer. You should also take this time, if you have not already, to ***Authorize this computer*** with your iTunes account.

iPod Part:

I would hook it up to a different USB port, perform a restore from iTunes and then see if it will sync with your now transfered music.

Comment: Nope, it's gone. I'm giving my old computer to someone else as a gift so i completely reformatted the hard drive. Thanks for your time. I was just in a hurry to get stuff done and it never occurred to me that the music hadn't transferred over to the thumb drive. Thanks for all your time.

Comment: Actually, it turned out there was a very simple solution. I went to my Apple iTunes account. Clicked on "previously purchased" and hit "download all" to my computer. I've got my music back. FAR F**KING OUT!! Again, thanks for all your time. I have no idea why I didn't try this before.